# Under what conditions does $f(x)$ equal its Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series

My question has 3 (similar) parts, and is as follows:

1. Under what conditions does $f(x)$ equal its Fourier Series for all $x$, $-L \leq x \leq L$?
2. Under what conditions does $f(x)$ equal its Fourier sine Series for all $x$, $0 \leq x \leq L$?
3. Under what conditions does $f(x)$ equal its Fourier cosine Series for all $x$, $0 \leq x \leq L$?

Comment: What do you know about $f$?  Are you asking for a complete characterization of pointwise convergence for Fourier series?

Comment: I think that the answer to all these is: when $f$ is continuous. When $f$ has a discontinuity, the Fourier series converges to the mean of the left and right limits.

Comment: We know that $f(x)$ is continuous and not much else unfortunately. I think in most cases the Fourier series converges to $f(x)$, but it is at the boundaries in particular i.e. $x =  0, L$ that most problems with convergence will arise.

Comment: No, continuity is **not** sufficient for pointwise convergence of the Fourier series.

Comment: @md2perpe Did you see Robert's comment ? The convergence of the Dirichlet kernel to the Dirac delta is messy. You [need $|f(x_0)-f(x)| < C |x_0-x|^\epsilon$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence) (Hölder continuity) for $f \ast D_n(x_0) \to f(x_0)$ nicely. Otherwise it becomes complicated and it has good chances to diverge. If you regularize the Dirichlet kernel then yes it converges to $f(x_0)$ everywhere it is continuous.

Comment: @reuns. No, I hadn't seen the comment. Thanks for giving me a notice. Now I learnt something. Probably I've seen the calculations before, but haven't remembered more than the need of continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourier series of a periodic continuous function of bounded variation converges pointwise to the function.  On the other hand, the Fourier series of a periodic continuous function can diverge at infinitely many points.  See e.g. R.E. Edwards, ["Fourier Series - A Modern Introduction"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=nB6JnQAACAAJ), section 10.3.1.

Comment: I would mention the convolution with the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)

Answer (score -1):

For your first part, any function which will be periodic with period 2L can be decomposed into fourier series and will take exact value for all the point's, given it is equal at -L,L and has no discontinuances in between. If it has discontinouities, it will take the average value between the two ends(Dirichlet theorem).

Sine has the same conditions as above with the additional condition that the function should be odd.In cosine, the function should be even.

Comment: You did not include all the requirements for Dirichlet's theorem.